# BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle causing Symfony CMF routes to stop working

Tags: symfony, localization, url-routing, symfony-cmf

I've got a Symfony CMF project up and running. I'm now trying to get localised routes for static content, and opted for BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle.

As soon as i enable the bundle, my symfony cmf routes stop working

```
Controller "Controller\ContentController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$contentDocument" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

Any one else experienced this? or have any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: could it be that be simple overwrites the main router alias? i have some vague recollection that there was a problem with some bundle doing that. you should try to make it stop doing that and overwrite router.default if that is what it wants, or register it with the chain router if its providing an additional router

Comment: this might be related to the issue in the JMS bundle for i18n routes: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/pull/102